# How do I restrict an input field to lowercase alpha, numeric and dashes only in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to restrict which characters can be typed into an input field on a form. The form has been created using Gravity Forms in WordPress, but that's not really important.

It's a username field, and so I want to restrict the characters to only lowercase alpha characters, numbers and dashes. If the user types any other type of number, I want nothing to happen.

I am part of the way there but need some help to finish this.

From [this article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Allow-only-AlphaNumeric-Alphabets-and-Numbers-characters-and-space-only-in-TextBox-using-Javascript.aspx), I've taken and tweaked this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var specialKeys = new Array();
     specialKeys.push(8);  //Backspace
     specialKeys.push(46); //Delete
     specialKeys.push(35); //End
     specialKeys.push(37); //Left
     specialKeys.push(39); //Right
 
     function IsAlphaNumeric(e) {
         var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
         var ret = ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
         document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
         return ret;
     }
</script>
```

The form input field is this:

```
<input name="input_16" id="input_1_16" type="text" value="" class="medium" maxlength="80" aria-describedby="gfield_description_1_16" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

I got as far as this in my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input_1_16").on("input", function(){
        // Don't know what to do!
    });
});
```

But as you can see, I am not sure how to update the input field to restrict the characters. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line `jQuery("input_1_16")` you miss the id selector, so you should select like that `jQuery("#input_1_16")`.
Another thing is the event that you need to work on is the keypress event, not input.

And I hope this code will help you :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input_1_16").keypress(function(e){
        if(!(/[a-z]|[0-9]|-/.test(e.key))){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_16" id="input_1_16" type="text" value="" class="medium" maxlength="80" aria-describedby="gfield_description_1_16" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: Wow, that is just what I was looking for. A much more elegant solution. And yes, sorry about missing the id selector. Just one thing before I mark this as the solution, yours allows underscores but not dashes. So, it needs to be changed to  if(!(/[a-z]|[0-9]|-/.test(e.key))) I think. Could you update that? Thanks!